# Angular routing issue when accessing url based on id

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My end goal is to allow users to access products when clicking on the item itself. So for each product item rendered in main.html the url is something like...

```
<a href="/products/{{ product.id }}">{{ product.title }}</a>
```

for example: right now when **inside** `localhost:8000/products/4/`  the itemDetails.html page shows but with a ton of 404 errors and

> Error: $injector:nomod Module Unavailable Module 'productFind' is not available

my **items.route.js** looks like this:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('items')
    .config(routerConfig);

  function routerConfig($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('itemDetails', {
        url: '/products/:id',
        templateUrl: 'items/itemDetails.html',
        controller: 'ItemDetailsController',
        controllerAs: 'itemDetails'
      })
  }

})();
```

and my **index.html** renders

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

the **index.module.js**

```
import { config } from './index.config';
import { routerConfig } from './index.route';
import { runBlock } from './index.run';
import { MainController } from './main/main.controller';
import '../app/components/items/items.module.js';
import { ItemDetailsController } from '../app/components/items/items.controller';
import { GithubContributorService } from '../app/components/githubContributor/githubContributor.service';
import { WebDevTecService } from '../app/components/webDevTec/webDevTec.service';
import { NavbarDirective } from '../app/components/navbar/navbar.directive';
import { MalarkeyDirective } from '../app/components/malarkey/malarkey.directive';

angular.module('productFind', ['ngAnimate', 'ngCookies', 'ngTouch', 'ngSanitize', 'ngMessages', 'ngAria', 'ngRoute', 'toastr', 'items'])
  .constant('malarkey', malarkey)
  .constant('moment', moment)
  .config(config)
  .config(routerConfig)
  .run(runBlock)
  .service('githubContributor', GithubContributorService)
  .service('webDevTec', WebDevTecService)
  .controller('MainController', MainController)
  .controller('ItemDetailsController', ItemDetailsController)
  .directive('acmeNavbar', NavbarDirective)
  .directive('acmeMalarkey', MalarkeyDirective);
```

My file structure looks like so...

```
productFind
    ...
    src
         app
              components
                   items
                        itemDetails.html
                        items.controller.js
                        items.module.js
                        items.route.js
                        itemsDataService.js
              main
                   main.controller.js
                   main.html
              index.module.js
              index.route.js
```

I'm assuming this is a routing issue so my question is: what am I doing wrong to be receiving this error message when I try to access the item/product details : localhost:8000/products/4/?

Comment: This is probably not your problem but you should use [ng-href](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref) instead of `href`.

Comment: @AJRichardson nice. definitely added. thank you. :)

Comment: Did that work, same issue here

Comment: @Modelesq No problem. I'm not too familiar with that error, but try checking the [$injector:nomod](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod) documentation if you haven't already.

Comment: @Gary no, it was just a tip from AJ Richardson

Comment: @AJRichardson yeah i feel as though i've read through it multiple times. Perhaps I'm just missing something somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `ngRoute` and `ng-view` with with `$stateProvider`.. `$stateProvider` is from UI-Router. Get UI-Router and use `ui.router` and `ui-view` instead. This alone should fix your problem.

UI-Router can be found [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).

Comment: Yes, nice catch here

Comment: Similarly could I just keep ngRoute and ng-view with $routeProvider?

Comment: Yes but there may be breaking changes..you should change all `$state.go(...)` statements and so forth. That being said, ui-router is a much better option.

Comment: Yes, this would fix it. I think I need to stick with $routeProvider and ng-view.

Comment: Well again just keep in mind the routing syntax/configuration is different with ngRoute. You are currently using the ui-router syntax/configuration.

Comment: @Lansana yep, i'll be reverting to $routeProvider. Lol I'm sure it will cause issues.